# Which one to chose - cursor vs WHILE loop in SQL Server for better performance?

Tags: sql-server-2008, while-loop, cursor

I came across below scenario, pseudo code version is

```
SELECT ProductID 
FROM ABC table 
WHERE (Some subquery)

For each record
       get value1 from DEF table where(some subquery with ProductID)
       
       Insert (ProductID, Value1) into GHI table 
       Insert (ProductID, Value1) into JKL table
End loop
```

I have 3 following approaches

1. Stored procedure with a cursor
2. Stored procedure with a `While` loop
3. a) Stored procedure to Get Product IDs
   b) C# Loop
   c) Stored procedure to insert data into tables

Which is the best approach in these or Is there any other best approach?

**Note**: This block code executed only once per day. There will be around 500 `ProductID`s on average per day.

Comment: I suggest option 4, set-based INSERT...SELECT queries with the SELECT query joining to ABC and DEF.

Comment: Cursor or WHILE loop are both horribly bad in SQL Server - choosing one over the other is chosing the smaller evil of two really horrible solutions. I'm with Dan Guzman - try to avoid **both** cursors and while loops whenever possible - and it's certainly possible to get around them in at least 90% of the cases. Just do some research and find a way!

Comment: @DanGuzman Could you please elaborate the approach?

Comment: @NShiva, this is an example gleaned from your pseudo code. Add a concrete T-SQL example to your question if you need more help for your actual use case and I'll elaborate with an answer. `INSERT INTO GHI_Table (ProductID, Value1)
OUTPUT inserted.ProductID, inserted.Value1 INTO JKL_Table (ProductID, Value1)
SELECT ABC_table.ProductID, DEF_Table.Value1
FROM ABC_table
JOIN DEF_Table ON DEF_Table.ProductID = ABC_table.ProductID;`